# How do you display a graph's replication factor in the gremlin-console?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I know for DSE graph, in `gremlin-console` you can create a graph with replication as follows

```
system.graph('graph_name').replication("{'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3}")
```

But how do you find out about an existing graph's replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, right now it's not possible to do via existing interfaces inside the gremlin-console. Before [5.1.3, there were separate options](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/reference/system/refOption.html) that was possible to fetch via `schema.config().describe()`, but they were replaced with `replication` & `systemReplication`.  Looks like (don't know 100%) that the strings provided via these options could be just passed to corresponding `CREATE KEYSPACE` commands, so if you have access to `cqlsh` then you can get replication factor from `describe keyspace graph_name`. Another possibility is to use Java code to fetch `Metadata`, and then extract replication factor via [getReplication call](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.5/com/datastax/driver/core/KeyspaceMetadata.html#getReplication--).